# Getting error in react ''rates' is not defined no-undef'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to render some data from an API using Axios which I have never tried before but I am at a serious loss, I am somewhat of a beginner with code so do bear with me.

Below is App.js component where there isn't much to see I am merely rendering the component that is doing all the work

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react'
import Rates from './Component/Rates';


function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
    
        <Rates/>
        
      </div>   
  );
}


export default App;
```

Then below here is my component rates where I am trying to render the data from the API

```
import React , { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


class Rates extends React.Component {

    state = {
        rates: {},
      };

      componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(``)
          .then(res => {
              console.log(res);
            this.setState({ rates: res.data });
          })
          
      }

    render(){
        return (
            
         
            <div>
                <h1>Exchange rates </h1>
                <button >Exchange rates</button>  
                
                  <ul>
                      {this.state.rates.map(rate => <li>{rates}</li>)}
                  </ul>
                    <h4>convert rates</h4>
                    <input></input> <br></br>
                    <input></input>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Rates
```

The line that keeps striking the undefined error is this line

```
{this.state.rates.map(rate => <li>{rates}</li>)}
```

Not too sure what is happening as I have read countless articles and watched a video or two.

Might I also add that

```
rates: {};
```

Is an object with key-value pairs so I am thinking maybe I need to convert my object into an array but even that I am not too sure of with Axios.

Any help would be grateful!

Comment: It's exactly as the error says. You don't have a standalone variable named `rates` defined anywhere. Looks like a typo: `.map(rate => <li>{rates}</li>)`

Comment: You are trying to perform an array operation on a an object

Comment: I've fixed this typo and I am currently getting another error TypeError: this.state.rates.map is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some edits here : https://codesandbox.io/s/still-wood-gcr0o?file=/src/App.js

Sump up of what I've done :

1. Use of async/await in the componentDidMount because fetching datas is asynchronous
2. The datas received by the request is in an object, not an array, so you can't use .map directly on it. You have to transform this object to an array.
3. It's an object so I had to edit the JSX to match the datas displayed with the datas received.

Comment: I changed everything above like you said and still getting this error TypeError: this.state.rates.map is not a function

Comment: replace ```this.state.rates.map``` by ```this.state.rates && this.state.rates.map```

Comment: the ```console.log(res)``` returns you the right datas ? can you send me the URL in the  Get request to try ?

Comment: oh I see the datas in the console.log but it's an object, not an array so you can't use .map you'll get an error, wait 2mins

Comment: please check the new edits here : https://codesandbox.io/s/still-wood-gcr0o?file=/src/App.js and the explanations in the answer

Comment: Thank you so MUCH, I will read all of this right away, where is the explanation would love to get a better understanding of how you managed it

Comment: maybe do you want me to comment some code directly in the file ?

Comment: Hey you can message me!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't map an object in javascript. You can map arrays. Change to `rates: []` in your constructor to avoid that error.
Then your axios is pointed at it's default target as you didn't specify the address of your get. Maybe look in your console to see what data is actually in 'res'.

Comment: Maybe add an example if needs to be an object, of how you can iterate over an object using Object.keys(), Object.values(), Object.entries(), or similar.

Comment: Fair enough, would be a good next step indeed. However, I am curious about what data his response holds. My guess is that he doens't need an object in the first place.

Comment: Hi, @Niels thanks for your response, much appreciated however I did try to turn rates into an array but it did not work and when I console.log(res) I get the pure object so the header the rates everything

Comment: Yes, knowing more information about the exact structure is critical. That being said, they mentioned "Is an object with key-value pairs".

Comment: Did you change the typo CertainPerformance pointed out? Then also, is response.data an array with numbers as you expect?